# replace string start with >

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, split

I'd like to retrieve the string from the text area and then remove the row which has starting char '>' (regardless whether has spaces in front of '>'), remove one or more than one occurrences of '-',
and then split the string to array with result as follow:

[BBAAAACC, CBDAAACC, EBAAAACC, FBAAAACC]

I have tried using regex follow but could not get the result.

```js
var data = document.getElementById("data").value.replace(/^[>-]+/g,"");
var array = data.split("\n");
console.log(array);
```

```html
        <textarea rows="15" cols="50" id="data">
              >1/1AA
            BBAAAACC-------------------------------------------------------------
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            -------------
            >2/1B
            CBDAAACC-------------------------------------------------------------
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            -------------
            >3/1-CD
            EBAAAACC-------------------------------------------------------------
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            -------------
            >4/1-11
            FBAAAACC-------------------------------------------------------------
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ------------- 
             </textarea>
```

Comment: Try [`var data = document.getElementById("data").value.match(/^\s*[A-Z]+/mg).map(x => x.trim())`](https://jsfiddle.net/ruts0a1w/) if you just need to get chunks of 1+ uppercase ASCII letters from the start of each line.

Comment: Will your results always be in the format of AAABBBCCC? you can change your regex to only match characters from A to Z [A-Z]+

Comment: I would like to remove the line starting with '>' (with/without spaces in front), and remove all '-'

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor, I have tried your solution and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a beginning, all your array needs is a bit of cleanup :

```js
var array = document
    .getElementById("data")
    .value
    .split("\n")
    .map(l => l.trim() // Removes extra spaces before and after
             .replace(/-/g,'')) // Removes all occurrences of '-'
    .filter(l => l.length && l[0] !== ">") // Keeps only the lines with a length and not beginning with '>'

console.log(array);
```

```html
<textarea rows="15" cols="50" id="data">
              >1/1AA
            BBAAAACC-------------------------------------------------------------
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            -------------
            >2/1B
            CBDAAACC-------------------------------------------------------------
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            -------------
            >3/1-CD
            EBAAAACC-------------------------------------------------------------
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            -------------
            >4/1-11
            FBAAAACC-------------------------------------------------------------
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ------------- 
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original idea is to remove lines starting with `>` and any `-` symbols, but it seems all you need is to extract chunks of 1+ uppercase ASCII  letters from the start of each line.

You may use

```
var data = document.getElementById("data").value.match(/^\s*[A-Z]+/mg).‌​map(x => x.trim())
```

where the regex, `/^\s*[A-Z]+/mg`, matches

- `^` - start of a line
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `[A-Z]+` - 1 or more uppercase ASCII letters
- `/mg` - multiline and global modifiers.

Note that in case you want to make sure you match the letters that are followed with `-`, you may append `(?=-)` positive lookahead at the end of the pattern.

Note that you still need to trim all the leading whitespaces matched with `\s*` using `.map(x => x.trim()` (or `.map(function(x) {return x.trim();})`). You may also capture the letters, `([A-Z]+)`, and then use `RegExp#exec()` in a loop grabbing `match[1]` values, but that involves more code.

See the JS demo:

```js
var data = document.getElementById("data").value.match(/^\s*[A-Z]+(?=-)/mg).map(x => x.trim());
console.log(data);
```

```html
<textarea rows="15" cols="50" id="data">
                >1/1AA
        BBAAAACC-------------------------------------------------------------
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -------------
        >2/1B
        CBDAAACC-------------------------------------------------------------
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -------------
        >3/1-CD
        EBAAAACC-------------------------------------------------------------
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -------------
        >4/1-11
        FBAAAACC-------------------------------------------------------------
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ------------- 
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a map and a filter - the other answer is ES5/6 so not working in older browsers:

```js
var array= document.getElementById("data").value
  .split("\n")
  .map(function(line) {
    line = line ? line.trim() : "";
    line = line.replace(/-/g, "");
    return line; })  
  .filter(function(line) {
    return line && line.indexOf(">") != 0;});
console.log(array);
```

```html
<textarea rows="15" cols="50" id="data">
              >1/1AA
            BBAAAACC-------------------------------------------------------------
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            -------------
            >2/1B
            CBDAAACC-------------------------------------------------------------
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            -------------
            >3/1-CD
            EBAAAACC-------------------------------------------------------------
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            -------------
            >4/1-11
            FBAAAACC-------------------------------------------------------------
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ------------- 
</textarea>
```